# Can InfluxDB store serialized objects?

Tags: java, serialization, influxdb

Currently evaluating InfluxDB and want to find out if serialized objects (e.g. using Java) can be stored / retrieved from InfluxDB and what is the process for it?

Comment: Seems like not much else is coming in; so .. in case my answer is helpful enough; please consider accepting ...

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InfluxDB), this database supports the following types of values:

> Values can be 64-bit integers, 64-bit floating points, strings, and booleans.

You can serialize Java objects into byte streams; and byte streams can be represented as *hex* strings.

So, *theoretically* the answer is yes - it should be possible to store serialized Java objects in this database. To read back, you just reverse that process.

If that is a good idea is a completely different question. It sounds rather inefficient; and storing **serialized** objects is by itself not a great idea. First of all, it is a big detour - turn an object into a byte stream into a hex string (and reverse that). Then: java object serialization has is a beast of its own - you have to be carefully for example to not introduce version incompatibilities. It is really annoying when you release a new version of your Java code and that code throws an exception when you try to deserialize *previously* stored objects.

Therefore more modern approaches prefer to serialize into different formats (JSON for example), or use tools to translate fields directly to different table columns.

Comment: Great, was thinking the same - there is theoretical way of storing serialized object into some other field (e.g. String field).. I am not experienced with all Pros/Cons of serialization (it is just being used by my team) - why is usually not a good idea? And what would be a better approach? Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer a bit. But in order to give a "this would work better" approach you should probably enhance your question. Like: what kind of objects to you want to serialize? What data needs to be stored, etc. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem